# How do I plot a graph through an indexed time in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, indexing, time, graph

I have a text file from where I have to retrieve data and plot a graph that will look like this. I want to plot a graph through which the machine had the status="on". I have tried to find the indices where the machine had an on status.

What I have done:

```
fid=fopen('power.txt');
line=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%d %f %s');
fclose(fid);

time=data{1};
power=data{2};
status=data{3};
status_on=strcmp(data{3},'on');

indices=find(status_on==0);
start_indices=indices+1;
%adding the first index where the status is on
start_indices=[1; start_indices];
%removing the last element as the last index will always have the value off
start_indices(end)=[];
end_indices=indices-1;

%Plotting Graph
plot(time,power,'-r');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Power (W)');
title('Sonications over time');
```

This graph just gives me the simple plot, but I need to make my graph look like this. Also I've been searching about marker use, do I need to make a specific code to get these markers or are there default Matlab functions?

Comment: Apparently when the power `status` is `OFF`, the second column (`power`) show `-1`, so look for that value in the second column, and everything not `-1` is then `ON`.

Comment: that's a good point. But I need my graph to be blank during the time it is off and there to be a line only when it is on which where I need help.

Comment: You can use a loop and add the markers with another call to `plot` and retain the current plot when adding new plots with `hold on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setting Values that are Not to be Plotted to `NaN`

You can fill the indices corresponding to the machine being "OFF" to `NaN` (Not a Number) and these will be ignored when plotting. Finding the local maximums and minimums using the `islocalmin()` and `islocalmax()` functions will allow the markers to be plotted based on index.

[image: Plot Ignoring OFF Values]

```
fid=fopen('power.txt');
line=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%d %f %s');
fclose(fid);

time=data{1};
power=data{2};
status=data{3};
status_on=strcmp(data{3},'on');

Off_Status = find(status == "off");
power(Off_Status) = "NaN";

Local_Minimum_Indices = islocalmin(power);
Local_Minimum_Indices(end-1) = 1;
Local_Maximum_Indices = islocalmax(power);
Local_Maximum_Indices(1) = 1;

%Plotting Graph
clf;
plot(time,power,'-r');
hold on
plot(time(Local_Maximum_Indices),power(Local_Maximum_Indices),'x','MarkerSize',10,'color','b');
plot(time(Local_Minimum_Indices),power(Local_Minimum_Indices),'s','MarkerSize',10,'color','g');

xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Power (W)');
title('Sonications over time');
ylim([0 max(power)+2]);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you, your code works. Is there any default function that I could add to get those specific markers in those specific points?

Comment: Almost by using `islocalmin()` and `islocalmax()` functions will allow you to find the indices where the markers need to be plotted. I edited my answer to accommodate this.